# Extending prototype with another prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I would like to extend a Prototype with another Prototype. This is my current code, tried also different things, and I cannot get it to work.

Network.prototype is an empty object, why?

```js
function Tester() {}

Tester.prototype = {
 clazz: 'Tester',
 start: function (url) {}
};


function NetworkTester() {}

NetworkTester.prototype = {
 clazz: 'NetworkTester',
        test: function (url) {
           this.start(); // this is undefined
        }
};


var helpers = {
    extend2: function (ChildClass, ParentClass) {
  ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
  ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
 }
};

helpers.extend2(NetworkTester, Tester);

console.log(NetworkTester.prototype);
```

I do not want to write NetoworkTester code like this:

```js
NetworkTester.prototype.clazz = 'NetworkTester';
NetworkTester.prototype.test = function (url) {
    this.start(); // this is undefined
};
```

I want it as I have it, it is prettier.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is this happening?**

Because you are overwriting the `.prototype` property with the following line:

```
ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
```

The object created by `new ParentClass();` is an object without any own properties (since you aren't assigning any in the constructor of `Tester`), thus it shows up as an empty Object in the dev tools.

The internal `[[Prototype]]` slot of `NetworkTester.prototype` is set though. You can have a look at it using the [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) method:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(NetworkTester.prototype)
```

**How can this be solved?**

To solve your dilemma, you would have to turn around your code order:

1. Create the new object for the `.prototype` property of the child, linking it to the parent:

   ```
   helpers.extend2(NetworkTester, Tester);
   ```
2. Define the `.prototype` properties of the child:

   ```
   NetworkTester.prototype.x = ...;
   NetworkTester.prototype.y = ...;
   ```

In order to avoid unnecessary constructor calls of the parent, you should probably use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead of the `new` operator.

So your code would look like this:

```
var helpers = {
    extend2: function (ChildClass, ParentClass) {
        ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
        ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
    }
};

function Tester() {}

Tester.prototype = {
    clazz: 'Tester',
    start: function (url) {}
};


function NetworkTester() {}

// This needs to happen before you assign to NetworkTester.prototype
helpers.extend2(NetworkTester, Tester);

NetworkTester.prototype.clazz = 'NetworkTester';
NetworkTester.prototype.test = function (url) {
    this.start(); // this is undefined
};

console.log(NetworkTester.prototype);
```

Comment: IMHO, using `Object.create` is the _only_ correct way to do this in ES5

Comment: @Alnitak `Object.create` only for object creation, or to populate the object using the second parameter as well?

Comment: only for creating the new prototype object - copying the prototype from an _instance_ of the superclass is just "wrong".

Comment: As far as I can see, start is defined: Try `console.log(NetworkTester.prototype.start);` or `var o = Object.create(NetworkTester.prototype); console.log(o.start);`